# Can't detect any signal in Pebble 2 HR

Tags: c, pebble-watch

I am one of the fews that bought a Pebble 2 with heart rate, with development purposes.

As you may know, this concrete watch doesn't provide power in the power line, so I'dont know how to connect an smartstrap that I have made.

I think I tried everything:

- Data and power connected with a 10K resistor between then, 5V in power line from an external source.
- Data and power connected with a 10K resistor between then, 3.3V in power line from an external source.
- Only 5V in data line, power unconnected.
- Only 3.3V in data line, power unconnected.

I'm monitoring the data line with an oscilloscope, and there is no variation in it. What I should expect?

I mean... When I run mi app, I suppose that Pebble should send some data to check if the smartstrap implements the link profile... but nothing, the line remains high all the time when I'm adding and external source and low when not.

I'm using the last version of the SDK (in ubuntu), and I'm getting a little bit frustrated...

Does somebody can help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The Pebble 2 does not support smartstraps of any kind, only the Pebble Time and Pebble Time Steel supported them. Sorry to disappoint you!